# Pre-fill UITextField when content type is set

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have the UITextField with content type as Email Address. So when the textField become firstResponser, there is my email on keyboard which can be clicked to fill the textField.

[image]

Is there any way to pre-fill UITextField with a value shown above the keyboard without that textfield to become firstResponser i.e. when viewController did appear ? Any source from where I can grab that email ?

Comment: No, is not possible to retrieve

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thanks. Any other way I can look in ?

Comment: save in prefs when first time user enters data and then again user enters data autofill from prefs